# C# Memory error when resizing window

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime-error

I have a simple form with some text box, label, and buttons, the problem is that it throws `attempted to read or write protected memory` every time I resize the window, there are no background tasks or nothing running when the form is showing, there is no code done yet, I just designed the UI and when I resize this error comes up. any ideas as to why this is? like I said, there is no code done yet, just dragged and dropped controls and arranged them.

[image]

this is the code in the .Designer

```
namespace MyProject
{
    partial class frmMain
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
       {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.dgvMain = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
            this.btnAbout = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.gbFilters = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.cbFiltered = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
            this.cbDomain = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.cbUser = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.btnNewPsswd = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.btnLogOut = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.lblUsr = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtUsr = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblPassword = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtPassword = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.cbShow = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox();
            this.lblDomain = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtDomain = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblUrl = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtUrl = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblNotes = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtNotes = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.btnDelete = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.gbMain = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.btnEdit = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dgvMain)).BeginInit();
            this.gbFilters.SuspendLayout();
            this.gbMain.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // dgvMain
            // 
            this.dgvMain.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            this.dgvMain.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            this.dgvMain.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.dgvMain.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
            this.dgvMain.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
            this.dgvMain.GridColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.dgvMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 96);
            this.dgvMain.Name = "dgvMain";
            this.dgvMain.ReadOnly = true;
            this.dgvMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(544, 331);
            this.dgvMain.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // btnAbout
            // 
            this.btnAbout.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue;
            this.btnAbout.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnAbout.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnAbout.Image = global::PasswordSavvy.Properties.Resources.info;
            this.btnAbout.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 433);
            this.btnAbout.Name = "btnAbout";
            this.btnAbout.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 55);
            this.btnAbout.TabIndex = 3;
            this.btnAbout.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // gbFilters
            // 
            this.gbFilters.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.gbFilters.Controls.Add(this.cbFiltered);
            this.gbFilters.Controls.Add(this.cbDomain);
            this.gbFilters.Controls.Add(this.cbUser);
            this.gbFilters.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 13);
            this.gbFilters.Name = "gbFilters";
            this.gbFilters.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(544, 77);
            this.gbFilters.TabIndex = 3;
            this.gbFilters.TabStop = false;
            this.gbFilters.Text = "Filters";
            // 
            // cbFiltered
            // 
            this.cbFiltered.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.cbFiltered.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.cbFiltered.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(243, 21);
            this.cbFiltered.Name = "cbFiltered";
            this.cbFiltered.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(217, 24);
            this.cbFiltered.TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // cbDomain
            // 
            this.cbDomain.AutoSize = true;
            this.cbDomain.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.cbDomain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(106, 44);
            this.cbDomain.Name = "cbDomain";
            this.cbDomain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(71, 20);
            this.cbDomain.TabIndex = 1;
            this.cbDomain.Text = "Domain";
            this.cbDomain.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // cbUser
            // 
            this.cbUser.AutoSize = true;
            this.cbUser.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.cbUser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(106, 18);
            this.cbUser.Name = "cbUser";
            this.cbUser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 20);
            this.cbUser.TabIndex = 0;
            this.cbUser.Text = "User";
            this.cbUser.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            // 
            // btnNewPsswd
            // 
            this.btnNewPsswd.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SeaGreen;
            this.btnNewPsswd.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnNewPsswd.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnNewPsswd.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(314, 433);
            this.btnNewPsswd.Name = "btnNewPsswd";
            this.btnNewPsswd.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(242, 55);
            this.btnNewPsswd.TabIndex = 5;
            this.btnNewPsswd.Text = "New Password";
            this.btnNewPsswd.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnNewPsswd.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnNewPsswd_Click);
            // 
            // btnLogOut
            // 
            this.btnLogOut.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue;
            this.btnLogOut.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.btnLogOut.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnLogOut.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnLogOut.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(66, 433);
            this.btnLogOut.Name = "btnLogOut";
            this.btnLogOut.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(242, 55);
            this.btnLogOut.TabIndex = 4;
            this.btnLogOut.Text = "Log Out";
            this.btnLogOut.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.btnLogOut.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnLogOut_Click);
            // 
            // lblUsr
            // 
            this.lblUsr.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblUsr.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.lblUsr.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 25);
            this.lblUsr.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 6, 3, 3);
            this.lblUsr.Name = "lblUsr";
            this.lblUsr.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 16);
            this.lblUsr.TabIndex = 2;
            this.lblUsr.Text = "User";
            // 
            // txtUsr
            // 
            this.txtUsr.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.txtUsr.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 47);
            this.txtUsr.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 3, 3, 6);
            this.txtUsr.MaxLength = 20;
            this.txtUsr.Name = "txtUsr";
            this.txtUsr.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtUsr.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(297, 22);
            this.txtUsr.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // lblPassword
            // 
            this.lblPassword.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblPassword.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.lblPassword.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 81);
            this.lblPassword.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 6, 3, 3);
            this.lblPassword.Name = "lblPassword";
            this.lblPassword.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(68, 16);
            this.lblPassword.TabIndex = 4;
            this.lblPassword.Text = "Password";
            // 
            // txtPassword
            // 
            this.txtPassword.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.txtPassword.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 103);
            this.txtPassword.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 3, 3, 6);
            this.txtPassword.MaxLength = 50;
            this.txtPassword.Name = "txtPassword";
            this.txtPassword.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtPassword.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(297, 22);
            this.txtPassword.TabIndex = 7;
            this.txtPassword.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            // 
            // cbShow
            // 
            this.cbShow.AutoSize = true;
            this.cbShow.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.cbShow.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.cbShow.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Goldenrod;
            this.cbShow.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(17, 134);
            this.cbShow.Name = "cbShow";
            this.cbShow.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 20);
            this.cbShow.TabIndex = 8;
            this.cbShow.Text = "Show ";
            this.cbShow.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this.cbShow.CheckStateChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cbShow_CheckStateChanged);
            // 
            // lblDomain
            // 
            this.lblDomain.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblDomain.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.lblDomain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 163);
            this.lblDomain.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 6, 3, 3);
            this.lblDomain.Name = "lblDomain";
            this.lblDomain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(55, 16);
            this.lblDomain.TabIndex = 7;
            this.lblDomain.Text = "Domain";
            // 
            // txtDomain
            // 
            this.txtDomain.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.txtDomain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 185);
            this.txtDomain.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 3, 3, 6);
            this.txtDomain.MaxLength = 50;
            this.txtDomain.Name = "txtDomain";
            this.txtDomain.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtDomain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(297, 22);
            this.txtDomain.TabIndex = 9;
            // 
            // lblUrl
            // 
            this.lblUrl.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblUrl.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.lblUrl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 219);
            this.lblUrl.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 6, 3, 3); 
            this.lblUrl.Name = "lblUrl";
            this.lblUrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 16);
            this.lblUrl.TabIndex = 9;
            this.lblUrl.Text = "URL";
            // 
            // txtUrl
            // 
            this.txtUrl.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.txtUrl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 241);
            this.txtUrl.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 3, 3, 6); 
            this.txtUrl.MaxLength = 255;
            this.txtUrl.Name = "txtUrl";
            this.txtUrl.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtUrl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(297, 22);
            this.txtUrl.TabIndex = 10;
            // 
            // lblNotes
            // 
            this.lblNotes.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblNotes.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.lblNotes.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 275);
            this.lblNotes.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 6, 3, 3);
            this.lblNotes.Name = "lblNotes";
            this.lblNotes.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 16);
            this.lblNotes.TabIndex = 11;
            this.lblNotes.Text = "Notes";
            // 
            // txtNotes
            // 
            this.txtNotes.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.txtNotes.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 297);
            this.txtNotes.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 3, 3, 6); 
            this.txtNotes.MaxLength = 255;
            this.txtNotes.Multiline = true;
            this.txtNotes.Name = "txtNotes";
            this.txtNotes.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtNotes.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(297, 126);
            this.txtNotes.TabIndex = 11;
            // 
            // btnDelete
            // 
            this.btnDelete.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Firebrick;
            this.btnDelete.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnDelete.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnDelete.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(202, 432);
            this.btnDelete.Name = "btnDelete";
            this.btnDelete.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(119, 36);
            this.btnDelete.TabIndex = 13;
            this.btnDelete.Text = "Delete";
            this.btnDelete.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // gbMain
            // 
            this.gbMain.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.btnEdit);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.btnDelete);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.txtNotes);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.lblNotes);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.txtUrl);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.lblUrl);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.txtDomain);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.lblDomain);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.cbShow);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.txtPassword);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.lblPassword);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.txtUsr);
            this.gbMain.Controls.Add(this.lblUsr);
            this.gbMain.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.gbMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(563, 13);
            this.gbMain.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.gbMain.Name = "gbMain";
            this.gbMain.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.gbMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(328, 475);
            this.gbMain.TabIndex = 0;
            this.gbMain.TabStop = false;
            this.gbMain.Text = "groupBox1";
            // 
            // btnEdit
            // 
            this.btnEdit.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue;
            this.btnEdit.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnEdit.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.btnEdit.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(77, 432);
            this.btnEdit.Name = "btnEdit";
            this.btnEdit.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(119, 36);
            this.btnEdit.TabIndex = 12;
            this.btnEdit.Text = "Edit";
            this.btnEdit.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            // 
            // frmMain
            // 
            this.AcceptButton = this.btnNewPsswd;
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.CancelButton = this.btnLogOut;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(904, 497);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnLogOut);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnNewPsswd);
            this.Controls.Add(this.gbFilters);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnAbout);
            this.Controls.Add(this.dgvMain);
            this.Controls.Add(this.gbMain);
            this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
            this.Name = "frmMain";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "Password Savvy";
            this.FormClosed += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventHandler(this.frmMain_FormClosed);
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.frmMain_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dgvMain)).EndInit();
            this.gbFilters.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.gbFilters.PerformLayout();
            this.gbMain.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.gbMain.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dgvMain;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnAbout;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox gbFilters;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnNewPsswd;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnLogOut;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox cbUser;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cbFiltered;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox cbDomain;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblUsr;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtUsr;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblPassword;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtPassword;
        private System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox cbShow;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblDomain;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtDomain;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblUrl;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtUrl;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblNotes;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtNotes;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnDelete;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox gbMain;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnEdit;
    }
}
```

all controls in the form are drag and drop

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Would you paste the code of the form's .designer file?

Comment: A stacktrace would be useful to know where the underlying exception was thrown from as well

Comment: any own made usercontrols on the form ?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly not a bug in WinForms or your C# code.  These errors are caused by either P/Invoke gone wrong or native modules loaded into your process.  The native modules could be loaded by you explicitly, or could be the result of AppInit DLLs or DLL's loaded by drivers or other processes.

Enable [Managed Debugging Assistants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/diagnosing-errors-with-managed-debugging-assistants) and update your video card drivers.  Check [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and the loaded [Modules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c8f14c9.aspx) tab of VS for unexpected dlls.  Process Explorer is another good tool to [identify third party modules](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/970920/using-process-explorer-to-list-dlls-running-under-the-outlook-exe-proc).

Comment: Thank you, i will try your suggestions..
also thanks  for providing the handy links